# Cumulative data in line chart - only 1 out of 2 is working but in the table if separated it will be working well

Tags: graph, powerbi, linegraph, cumulative-line-chart

First, I will explain the full scenario of my graph;

1. I need to create 2 cumulative data from 2 different file (which is same format but different revision). 1 will be the 'based line' and the latest file will be 'forecast'
2. I did the measure to get the cumulative data and when I run the visualization using table its ok (if separately, I mean based line is 1 table and forecast done in another table)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWg99.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ1w2.png)
3. Then, when I generated the line graph, cumulative for forecast is OK but cumulative for base line (in dark blue) is not cumulated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMkjl.png)
4. In modeling, I have connected the project number of both file. (But in the transform data, I have already ensure only 1 project was filtered, thus there's no other project in the data) - Is this is my mistake? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCG4W.png)

My expectation is the graph will be both in cumulative.